# How substring doesnt work on titanium?

Tags: titanium

I am using datepicker to select date,

and my source code for addEventlistener is here.

```
$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    var date = e.value;
Ti.API.info(date); // shows '[INFO] :   2014-04-07 21:28:34 +0000' on console
    date.substring(0,10);

});
```

Ti.API.info(date) shows correct data ,but
date.substring(0,10); shows error like this below

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      backtrace = "#0 () at :0";
[ERROR] :      line = 143;
[ERROR] :      message = "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'date.substring(0, 10)')";
[ERROR] :      name = TypeError;
[ERROR] :      sourceId = 329234912;
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///Users/temp/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/2E7B2C43-653A-4E38-BB04-F820AB2C3BC2/matomato.app/alloy/controllers/index.js";
[ERROR] :  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dates you could use:

```
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Answer (score 2):

convert date to String ,then you will be able to use substring

```
$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    var date = e.value;
        date= date.toString();   // check it
        date.substring(0,10); 
       Ti.API.info(date);       //'2014-04-07' 

});
```